# Mongo aggeregation limit while grouping

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection which im aggregating and grouping by the field "type". The final result should be just maximum of five documents in each type. But if i limit before group only five first docs will be grouped. if i limit after the group the first five types will return.

is there a way to do this without doing find() for each type , limiting to 5 and merging all the results ?

Answer (score -3):

If you can use C# (which according to my quick google-search about mongodb you do), you can do this with one of the GroupBy's which have an "ResultSelector-Function", like this:

```
var groups = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).
                GroupBy(
                        x => x/10, 
                        (key, elements) => new  { Key = key, Elements = elements.Take(5) }
                       );
```

About the speed of this code - I believe the group is completely build before the result-selector is instantiated - so a custom foreach over the input sequence and building the groups by hand might be faster (if you can somehow determine when you are done)

P.S.: On second thought - I doubt my answer is the one you want. I had a look at the mongo-DB documentation, and "map" in combination with a suitable "reduce" function might be exactly what you want.

Comment: sorry this is not the answer im looking for.